# Cannot read property 'postMessage' in webview Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview, and this webview can show a popup and is displaying ok. When I click on a button of this popup, it is supposed to check some data and close this popup. But this does not happen, when I click the button it doesn't do anything.

I can see in the logs this error:

```
2022-03-21 17:32:06.390 8841-8841/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(74)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null", source: https://xxxx/xxxx/ViewFinTs?style= (74)
```

How can I fix this?